# mysql PreparedStatement update not working. Exception is not clear

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

**Background:**
Need to write PreparedStatement to update table in mysql.
Using PreparedStatement, I am able to do Select and Insert by passing parameters in different methods of same class. But somehow update is giving exception. SQL is extremely simple. In Debug mode, I can see that query is correct and if copy pasted on workbench, it works just fine.

select VERSION();
8.0.28

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE account_main (
    account_id INT,
    customer_id INT,
    branch_id INT,
    is_active BOOLEAN,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_id)
);
```

**class:**

```
public class AccountMain {
    private int accountId;
    private int customerId;
    private int branchId;
    private boolean isActive;
    private Date createDate;
    private Date lastModified;
//omitting setter,getter etc.
```

**java method:**

```
public AccountMain updateAccount(AccountMain accountMain) {
        System.out.println("updating account - "+accountMain);
        String q="UPDATE account_main SET customer_id = ? WHERE account_id = ? ;";
        try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(q)) {
            ps.setInt(1, accountMain.getCustomerId());
            ps.setInt(2, accountMain.getAccountId());
            int rc = ps.executeUpdate(q);
            System.out.println("rc: 1 if row updated. 0 if nothing updated. rc:" + rc);
            AccountMain accountMainUpdated = getAccountMain(accountMain.getAccountId());
            return accountMainUpdated;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE account_id = ?' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1335)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2085)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1246)
    at com.sv.javadbbasic.stmt.AccountDAOImpl.updateAccount(AccountDAOImpl.java:94)
    at com.sv.javadbbasic.AppMain.demoAccountDAO(AppMain.java:38)
    at com.sv.javadbbasic.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:15)
```

ps statement value in Intellij if I debug:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: UPDATE account_main SET customer_id = 4 WHERE account_id = 2 ;
```

Other preparedstatements that are working fine in same class:

```
INSERT INTO account_main (account_id, customer_id, branch_id, is_active) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?);
select * from account_main where account_id = ?;
```

Comment: Check what `accountMain.getCustomerId()` is returning. The error message says that there's something wrong in the piece of query where you're passing the ID

Comment: In Debug mode, if i do ps evaluation in Intellij, it shows :


com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: UPDATE account_main SET customer_id = 4 WHERE account_id = 2 ;

Comment: May sound illogical, but try removing space and semicolon after `account_id=?`

Comment: The problem is using `executeUpdate(<string>)` where you should use `executeUpdate()` (no argument). The first signature tries to execute the query string directly, including its `?` parameter placeholders. You need to execute the prepared version, with the values you bound as parameters.

Comment: Didn't even notice that, @BillKarwin is right

Comment: @BillKarwin - thanks a lot. You are right. Thanks for looking into it.